# Merge two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
     date                     at        weight  status    buy_ts               sell_ts
---  -------------------  ------  ------------  --------  -------------------  -------------------
  0  2010-01-03 00:00:00  1.4286             7  buy       2010-01-04 01:47:00  nan
  1  2010-01-03 00:00:00  1.4288             7  buy       2010-01-04 00:00:00  nan
  2  2010-01-03 00:00:00  1.4289             7  buy       2010-01-04 00:00:00  nan
  3  2010-01-04 00:00:00  1.442             25  buy       2010-01-05 00:00:00  nan
  4  2010-01-05 00:00:00  1.4422            15  sell      nan                  2010-01-06 14:03:00
  5  2010-01-05 00:00:00  1.4423            15  sell      nan                  2010-01-06 14:03:00
  6  2010-01-05 00:00:00  1.4424            15  sell      nan                  2010-01-06 14:03:00
  7  2010-01-06 00:00:00  1.4403            18  sell      nan                  2010-01-07 00:04:00
  8  2010-01-06 00:00:00  1.4404            18  sell      nan                  2010-01-07 00:05:00
  9  2010-01-06 00:00:00  1.4405            18  sell      nan                  2010-01-08 08:54:00
 10  2010-01-07 00:00:00  1.4313            26  buy       2010-01-08 00:07:00  nan
 11  2010-01-07 00:00:00  1.4314            26  buy       2010-01-08 00:07:00  nan
 12  2010-01-07 00:00:00  1.4316            26  sell      nan                  2010-01-08 00:10:00
```

`buy_ts` and `sell_ts` contains a Python `datetime.datetime` object

I would like to create a new column called `merged_ts` which contains the datetime.dateime object from `buy_ts` or `sell_ts` (when one column has value the other is always nan so it is not possible that both columns are populated).

Comment: `df['merged']=df.pop('buy_ts').fillna(df.pop('sell_ts'))` this will delete the `buy_ts` and `sell_ts` columns and will create an new col your "merged" data simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['merged'] = df['buy_ts'].combine_first(df['sell_ts'])
```